# Raising event to main thread while reading stream asynchronously

Tags: multithreading, events, asynchronous, f#

I'm trying to fetch sensor's output as infinite stream without blocking main application. Each iteration of reading loop must inform main thread with event containing array of bytes I've just read. I need methods for start and stop generating this event stream. Event raising is supposed to be like MouseMove event so I can easily listen to them and make all aggregations from Event module. I've tried a lot with async {} and threading and a bit with backgroundworker.

Sensor acts pretty much like /dev/urandom linux file except inner structure

```
type SensorReader() = 
    let progress = new Event<_>();

    member this.BeginRead () =
        let sr = new IO.StreamReader("/dev/urandom") 
        let charBuffer = Array.zeroCreate<byte> 16
        let rec loop () = async {
        //read next 16-byte chunk and trigger event to the main Thread
            return! loop() }
        Async.Start(loop())

    member this.ProgressChanged = progress.Publish
```

or something like

```
type SensorReader() =
    let progress = new Event<_>()


    let worker = new BackgroundWorker(WorkerReportsProgress = true, 
                                      WorkerSupportsCancellation = true)

    let sr = new IO.StreamReader("/dev/urandom") 
    let charBuffer = Array.zeroCreate<char> 16

    do worker.DoWork.Add(fun args ->

        let rec iterate() =
            if worker.CancellationPending then
                args.Cancel <- true
            //else read next chunk and report event

    iterate())

//do worker.ProgressChanged.Add(fun args ->
//    progressChanged.Trigger(*our new data from sensor*)

member this.ProgressChanged = progressChanged.Publish

member this.BeginReadAsync() = worker.RunWorkerAsync()
member this.EndReadAsync() = worker.CancelAsync()
```

Hope you guys will help me, thanks

Comment: What's wrong with your second example?

Comment: I just can't make it work properly. All my previous attempts were mostly about changing commented part "//else read next chunk and report event". I didn't find way to read and then raise event on main thread. That's a question "how to do it right?"

Comment: Only code that interacts with UI controls needs to run on the main UI thread. In the `ProgressChanged` handler, pass a lambda that updates the controls to `Control.Invoke`.

Comment: I think there's something I don't understand. Is main thread the same as UI thread? I'm not going to use UI at all. Control.Invoke is defined in Windows.Forms. Сan it be used in my task?

Comment: If this isn't a forms app, why do you need the event to fire on the main thread? Can you explain more of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm working on reactive system(robot). I want to create a computation that takes the current state of the robot (composition of data from sensors and some predefined values) as the input in form of events and quickly respond to them (filter, merge then map some function like writing to output devices) to get an appropriate behavior. The majority of sensors are presented as special linux files that write as long as we read them. The problem is that this reading will block application so I need more clever way to raise this events